# RowFilter RegexFilter - How to avoid Integer being convert to string with a comma?

Tags: java, swing, javax

I applied a `RowFilter.regexFilter(...)` to my table and the filtering on `Integer` columns doesn't work how it should. I figured that in `RowFilter.RegexFilter.include()`, the `Integer`-value to be evaluated is converted to a `String` with commas.

```
18 -> 18
4820 -> 4,820
85898 -> 85,898
```

However I want it to be a plain `Integer`-String without any commas.
I'm setting the RowFilter for my table like this:

```
String myfilterString = "^\Q46\E"; // integer value should start with "46"
RowFilter<Object, Object> patternFilter = RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + myFilterString, columnIndex);
myTable.setRowFilter(patternFilter);
```

How can I change the behaviour here?

Comment: Please show the code that does this

Comment: That's a lot of code, I will add the part where I set the RowFilter for the table in a minute.

Comment: You can change the formatting (as explained in my answer) just before putting the string 'on display' (I'm unclear on exactly how you mean to do this)

Comment: I'm not speaking about displaying the value, just filtering (RowFilter in JTable).

Comment: You question is not completely clear.  But to convert an integer to a String without commas, simply do `Integer.toString(n)` where `n` is an `int`.

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE / MCVE, short, runnable, compilable, with hardcoded value for model in local variable

Answer (score 2):

If you store Integer data in the table then the Regex will work on the Integer value.

The ways the Integer is formatted by the renderer has no effect on the actual data in the TableModel.

So make sure your TableModel holds Integer values and that you have overridden the `getColumnClass(...)` method of the TableModel to return `Integer.class` for that column.

Comment: My TableModel is returning Integer.class for the column, but the Integer is not formatted correctly. Do you have any other suggestions? :/

Comment: @sfandler to prepare, format data before are added (requirements and standard for all programing, incl SQL) to XxxTableModel, there is an option to hold original data and formatted data in another column, column with original data can be removed from JTables view (ths method just ot hide the column, data are still in the model, column can be again added to JTables view), required to understand basics implemented in model_to_view

Comment: @sfandler I don't see any formatting characters when I use an Integer value. You were asked hours ago to post your `SSCCE` / [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.